# Angular subscribes activeMQ through wss and gets header is too large

Tags: angular, activemq-classic

my angular 12 project subscribes ActiveMQ through STOMP and recently I got `Header is too large > 8192` error in ActiveMQ console. Can anyone please help to identify the potential reasons and solutions?

I am currently using

```
"@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "^8.0.0",
"@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.2",
```

```
public subscribe(destination: string, messageQueueConfiguration: MessageQueueConfiguration): Subscription {
    this._messageQueueConfiguration = messageQueueConfiguration;
    this._rxStompService = rxStompServiceFactory(this.buildConfiguration(this._options.isDebug));

    this._subscription = this._rxStompService.watch(destination).subscribe(async (stompMessage: StompMessage) => {
      this.process(stompMessage);
    });
    return this._subscription;
  }
```

Here is the warning message from ActiveMQ console

[image]

Here is the error messages in angular project (chrome console)

[image]

Comment: Are you able to capture the HTTP header output or run the request through a HTTP proxy? ActiveMQ's HTTP engine (Eclipse Jetty) is rejecting the message due to a header being too large. This is done to protect the broker from flooding.

Comment: Thank you Matt for pointing it out. Just realise for some reason, the cookies are also included in the request header. After deleting all the cookies, it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the chrome's dev tool, I realise that, for some reason, all the cookies are also included in the request header. I manually clean up the cookies and it starts working.